# flutter_libserialport packet exchange

Tags: flutter, serial-port, packet, xmodem

New to Flutter, but have years of experience writing C code for embedded devices. Trying to wrap my head around how the data flow works with Dart and with this particular library. I'm finding examples of how to send a few bytes back and forth to do some simple things with an Arduino, but I'm not finding anything that shows a structured packet exchange over a serial link for something like XModem. Where you receive a fixed sized packets (128 bytes) and reassemble them at the receiver.

[XModem packet exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paKuN.png)

I've managed to get some code that will wait until at least 5 bytes are received before doing anything with it, and it work if I send one byte at a time. But if I send a bunch of bytes, it prints them all. The way they get split up is not consistent either (`data.length` is not consistent from `upcomingData.listen(data)`). Tried making buffer Uint8List, but appending data to it with `.add` or `.addAll` doesn't seem to work.

I know this code is not the best way to do it, but it's all that I've been able to get working. Haven't figured out the SerialPortBuffer() and can't find any examples. Have also tried using ChunkedStreamReader without any success (also no examples beyond what's in the API documents)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
`
List<String> availablePort = SerialPort.availablePorts;
SerialPort port = SerialPort('COM8');
SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port);
List<Uint8List> buffer = []; // Doesn't work with just Uint8List 
int bufferIndex = 0;

debugPrint('Available Ports: $availablePort');

// Incoming serial port stream
Stream<Uint8List> upcomingData = reader.stream.map((data) {
  return data;
});

try {
  port.openReadWrite();
  initSerial(port);

  // Send data to serial port
  serialSend(port, 'Testing');

  upcomingData.listen((data) {
    buffer.add(data);
    bufferIndex += data.length;

    if (bufferIndex >= 5) {
      String strBuffer = '';
      for (var letter in buffer) {
        strBuffer += String.fromCharCodes(letter);
      }
      debugPrint('Buffer: $strBuffer');
      bufferIndex = 0;
      buffer = [];
      strBuffer = '';
    }
  });
} on SerialPortError catch (err, _) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(SerialPort.lastError);
  }
  port.close();
} finally {
  // Catch anything not caught
}
L
```

**EDIT (some progress)**

So, after trying unsuccessfully to use ChunkedStreamReader and to figure out SerialPortBuffer, I discovered that Uint8List cannot be manipulated like other List in Flutter.  Seems easier to make the buffer as List and then change it back to Uint8List if need by using `String.fromCharCodes()`.  Using int for Uint8 data seems wasteful, but I can't figure out a better way.

```
`
    List<String> availablePort = SerialPort.availablePorts;
    SerialPort port = SerialPort('COM8');
    SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port);
    List<int> buffer = [];
    int bufferIndex = 0;

    debugPrint('Available Ports: $availablePort');

    // Incoming serial port stream
    Stream<Uint8List> upcomingData = reader.stream.map((data) {
      return data;
    });

    try {
      port.openReadWrite();
      initSerial(port);

      // Send data to serial port
      serialSend(port, 'Testing');

      upcomingData.listen((data) {
        buffer += data;
        bufferIndex += data.length;

        if (bufferIndex >= 5) {
          String strBuffer = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
          debugPrint('Buffer: $strBuffer');
          bufferIndex = 0;
          buffer = [];
        }
      });
    } on SerialPortError catch (err, _) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(SerialPort.lastError);
      }
      port.close();
    } finally {
      // Catch anything not caught
    }

L
```

Comment: I'm going to keep it as Uint8 in the end.  I'm only using the strings to print it out to make sure that the letter I sent from a terminal is the one that is received.  Saves time looking up the ASCII codes.

Comment: ok so what was wrong with `ChunkedStreamReader`? it does not read 128 fixed size packets?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it.  The examples only show opening files.  The way of opening the  stream:  `Stream<Uint8List> upcommingData = reader.stream.map((data)`  is different than the way streams are opened in most of videos I find online that create counters or name generators.

Comment: `final r = ChunkedStreamReader(upcommingData);
    Stream<List<int>> substream = r.readStream(5);

      substream.listen((data) async {
        var packet = data;
        debugPrint('Packet: $packet');
      });`

Comment: I only get back the first character I send.  Even it I send several.

Comment: the same with [readChunk](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader/readChunk.html) ?

Comment: Could not get that working either.